# Can I export pandas DataFrame to Excel stripping tzinfo?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, time-series, tzinfo

I have a timezone aware TimeSeries in pandas 0.10.1. I want to export to Excel, but the timezone prevents the date from being recognized as a date in Excel.

```
In [40]: resultado
Out[40]: 
fecha_hora
2013-04-11 13:00:00+02:00    31475.568
2013-04-11 14:00:00+02:00    37263.072
2013-04-11 15:00:00+02:00    35979.434
2013-04-11 16:00:00+02:00    35132.890
2013-04-11 17:00:00+02:00    36356.584
```

If I strip the tzinfo with `.tz_convert(None)`, the date gets converted to UTC:

```
In [41]: resultado.tz_convert(None)
Out[41]: 
fecha_hora
2013-04-11 11:00:00    31475.568
2013-04-11 12:00:00    37263.072
2013-04-11 13:00:00    35979.434
2013-04-11 14:00:00    35132.890
2013-04-11 15:00:00    36356.584
```

Is there a TimeSeries method to apply `.replace(tzinfo=None)` to each date in the index?

Alternativelly, is there a way to properly export time-aware TimeSeries to Excel?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create a copy without timezone.

```
import pandas as pa

time = pa.Timestamp('2013-04-16 10:08', tz='Europe/Berlin')
time_wo_tz = pa.datetime(year=time.year, month=time.month, day=time.day, 
                         hour=time.hour, minute=time.minute, second=time.second,
                         microsecond=time.microsecond)
```

When you want to convert the whole index of the timeseries, use a list comprehension.

```
ts.index = [pa.datetime(year=x.year, month=x.month, day=x.day, 
                        hour=x.hour, minute=x.minute, second=x.second, 
                        microsecond=x.microsecond) 
            for x in ts.index]
```

Comment: Actually, I didn't want to loop over the index. I believe .replace is clearer than using each component to recreate the date.

Comment: Ok. But since datetimes are immutable (and should be immutable), you probably won't find such a function doing this without creating a copy.

What could help is some sort of converting function while writing to the csv. While this seem to exist for `write_csv`, it does not for `to_csv` and `to_excel`.