# Strip timezone info in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have been struggling with removing the time zone info from a column in a pandas dataframe. I have checked the following question, but it does not work for me:

[Can I export pandas DataFrame to Excel stripping tzinfo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967468/can-i-export-pandas-dataframe-to-excel-stripping-tzinfo)

I used tz_localize to assign a timezone to a datetime object, because I need to convert to another timezone using tz_convert. This adds an UTC offset, in the way "-06:00". I need to get rid of this offset, because it results in an error when I try to export the dataframe to Excel.

Actual output

```
2015-12-01 00:00:00-06:00
```

Desired output

```
2015-12-01 00:00:00
```

I have tried to get the characters I want using the str() method, but it seems the result of tz_localize is not a string. My solution so far is to export the dataframe to csv, read the file, and to use the str() method to get the characters I want.

Is there an easier solution?

Comment: doesn't `df['datetime'].dt.tz_localize(None)` work? replace `datetime` with what ever your column name is

Comment: Thanks. It doesn´t work. The format of the date is "2015-12-01 00:00:00-06:00". I used "to_datetime" to convert the original date format to a datetime object, in order to apply "tz_localize" to convert to another time zone. It seems tz_localize adds that offset and I have not found how to get rid of it.

Comment: closely related (if not dupe) [Convert pandas timezone-aware DateTimeIndex to naive timestamp, but in certain timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16628819/10197418)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If your series contains only datetimes, then you can do:

`my_series.dt.tz_localize(None)`

This will remove the timezone information ( it will not change the time) and return a series of naive local times, which can be exported to excel using to_excel() for example.

Comment: What if the pandas dataframe contains  columns that are other than datetimes?  I get errors like "TypeError: index is not a valid DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex"

Comment: @DaveX then you would do `my_df[time_columns] = my_df[time_columns].dt.tz_localize(None)` where `time_columns` is a list of column names that have datetime dtype

Answer (score 13):

Maybe help strip last 6 chars:

```
print df
                    datetime
0  2015-12-01 00:00:00-06:00
1  2015-12-01 00:00:00-06:00
2  2015-12-01 00:00:00-06:00

df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].astype(str).str[:-6]
print df
              datetime
0  2015-12-01 00:00:00
1  2015-12-01 00:00:00
2  2015-12-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I had to convert it to a string first.

Comment: You can use `replace(tzinfo=None)` like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944047/remove-pytz-timezone/#answer-10944136

Comment: @Beatriz Fronseca Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: this works okay I guess, but in my experience it is better to convert to a datetime class and then use `pd.Series.dt.tz_localize` to set the timezone to `None`, as @Diego Mora Cespedes suggested in his answer on this post. Better to not rely on the date format and it is prob a lot faster.

Comment: @quantif - absolutely agree ;)

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 9):

To remove timezone from **all datetime columns** in a DataFrame with mixed columns just use:

```
for col in df.select_dtypes(['datetimetz']).columns:
    df[col] = df[col].dt.tz_localize(None)
```

if you can't save df to excel file just use this (not delete timezone!):

```
for col in df.select_dtypes(['datetimetz']).columns:
    df[col] = df[col].dt.tz_convert(None)
```

Comment: Wrong answer: `tz_convert(None)` will convert to UTC prior to dropping the timezone indicator, so that `pd.Timestamp('2015-12-01 00:00:00-06:00').tz_convert(None)` will result in `Timestamp('2015-12-01 06:00:00')`.

Answer (score 4):

Following Beatriz Fonseca's suggestion, I ended up doing the following:

```
from datetime import datetime
df['dates'].apply(lambda x:datetime.replace(x,tzinfo=None))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all timezones from all datetime64 columns you could use this

```py
for col in df.select_dtypes(include=['datetime64[ns, UTC]']).columns:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: x.tz_localize(None))
```

Answer (score -1):

If it is always the last 6 characters that you want to ignore, you may simply slice your current string:

```
>>> '2015-12-01 00:00:00-06:00'[0:-6]
'2015-12-01 00:00:00'
```