# How do you convert a timestamp with nano-seconds to just seconds with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a Windows Event logs which are in an ElasticSearch cluster.  I am using Pandas to query ES vis the API. The output for the datetime field is initially an "object". Using pandas.to_datetime I have successfully converted it to a Dtype of "datetime64[ns, UTC]".

However the data in the field in an undesired format of, yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss+00:00.

I don't want the "+00:00" part. I have tried pandas.to_datetime with format to no avail. Here is how I am converting the object.

```
services["datetime"]=pd.to_datetime(services["datetime"])
```

Here is the field output, 2020-08-31 11:02:03+00:00
Here is the desired output, 08/31/2020 11:02:03

Not sure how to get there.

Answer (score 0):

One more step:

```
services["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(services["datetime"])
services["datetime"] = services["datetime"].dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Thanks. I found this to remove the timezone. 
`type_10_df["datetime"]=type_10_df["datetime"].dt.tz_localize(None)`

Answer (score 0):

It's not nano-seconds, it's the time-zone. It's part of the date time in pandas, and `+00:00` just means it on UTC time.

There are several options to eliminate time-zone awareness in pandas. Check out those questions:

[How to remove timezone from a Timestamp column in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49198068/how-to-remove-timezone-from-a-timestamp-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

[Strip timezone info in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34506112/strip-timezone-info-in-pandas)

[Convert pandas timezone-aware DateTimeIndex to naive timestamp, but in certain timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628819/convert-pandas-timezone-aware-datetimeindex-to-naive-timestamp-but-in-certain-t)

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using this...

`type_10_df["datetime"]=pd.to_datetime(type_10_df["datetime"])`
`type_10_df["datetime"]=type_10_df["datetime"].dt.tz_localize(None)`