# Convert dtypes object field in datetime with correct time zone pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timezone-offset

I load from a PostGre Database the following Pandas DataFrame:

```
df
Out[162]: 
                      date_time    production_mw
0     2019-01-01 00:00:00+01:00  10.000000000000
1     2019-01-01 01:00:00+01:00  10.000000000000
2     2019-01-01 02:00:00+01:00  10.000000000000
3     2019-01-01 03:00:00+01:00  10.000000000000
4     2019-01-01 04:00:00+01:00  10.000000000000
                        ...              ...
8755  2019-12-31 19:00:00+01:00  10.000000000000
8756  2019-12-31 20:00:00+01:00  10.000000000000
8757  2019-12-31 21:00:00+01:00  10.000000000000
8758  2019-12-31 22:00:00+01:00  10.000000000000
8759  2019-12-31 23:00:00+01:00  10.000000000000

[8760 rows x 2 columns]
```

where

```
df.dtypes
Out[163]: 
date_time        object
production_mw    object
dtype: object
```

Cool, my desire is to convert the field date_time to datetime with the correct timezone, that in this case in CET timezone (+01:00)

I did it in two steps

```
df.date_time = pd.to_datetime(df.date_time, utc=True)
df.date_time=df.date_time.dt.tz_convert('CET')
```

And i correctly get

```
 df.dtypes
Out[166]: 
date_time        datetime64[ns, CET]
production_mw                 object
dtype: object
```

In many cases I have access only to the dataframe df with date_time field in that format (YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss +/- offset), without actually knowing whats the corresponding timezone, is there a way for python to automatically detect the offset to which timezone corresponds, without me setting it manually?

Comment: For me working well in pandas `1.2.3` if use `df.date_time = pd.to_datetime(df.date_time)`, for you not?

Comment: Instead of CET, use a proper IANA time zone name, like 'Europe/Berlin' in this case. If you don't know the time zone, work with UTC. I'd rather do *all* the work in UTC, time zone only for output if needed ("human-readable").

Comment: In general: no, you cannot infer a time zone from a UTC offset unambiguously. Only time zone + datetime -> UTC offset.

Answer (score 0):

I know that is not exacty what I asked, but I am more interested in keeping the hh:mm:ss the same as in the input than setting the right time zone. So I just removed the time zone information

with the command

```
df['date_time']=df['date_time'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(tzinfo=None))
```

and i get

```
df
Out[199]: 
               date_time    production_mw
0    2019-01-01 00:00:00  10.000000000000
1    2019-01-01 01:00:00  10.000000000000
2    2019-01-01 02:00:00  10.000000000000
3    2019-01-01 03:00:00  10.000000000000
4    2019-01-01 04:00:00  10.000000000000
                 ...              ...
8755 2019-12-31 19:00:00  10.000000000000
8756 2019-12-31 20:00:00  10.000000000000
8757 2019-12-31 21:00:00  10.000000000000
8758 2019-12-31 22:00:00  10.000000000000
8759 2019-12-31 23:00:00  10.000000000000

[8760 rows x 2 columns]

df.dtypes
Out[200]: 
date_time        datetime64[ns]
production_mw            object
dtype: object
```

so the hours are not shifted (I am doing analysis on solar power plants and say the production peak is at midnight + 6 UTC is not ideal -) )

The solution I applied is at the following link

[Strip timezone info in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34506112/strip-timezone-info-in-pandas)

Cheers

Comment: handling of UTC offsets is pretty straight forward, you don't have to remove information, effectively reducing data quality. Btw. see [Convert pandas timezone-aware DateTimeIndex to naive timestamp, but in certain timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16628819/10197418) - you don't need an apply/lambda here (less efficient).

Comment: also note https://stackoverflow.com/a/62656878/10197418 - localizing to None can give you unexpected side-effects...

Comment: @MrFuppes thank you for the link, I check but in that case it is already a Timestamp, I start from an object type and I mess with the hours to covert it as a datime object aware of the timezone

Comment: I think the linked question *is* the point here, not conversion from string to datetime (that's the easy part). Just so you know what to expect: the UTC offset gives you at least some information on the source of the date/time (a IANA time zone name would be better). If you remove it, this info is lost. Of course it depends on the context if that is the right or wrong thing to do. In any case, a UTC offset does *not* give you ***the correct time zone*** (see my comment under the question).

Comment: @MrFuppes your comments are all really relevants and I agree with you on all of them . What i mean it is that probably for my technical limitations in python, to convert the field date_time that is dtypes object to datetime, I must fix utc=True, otherwise I get an error, since has the offset. At that point I mess up with the hours since time is converted to UTC.